# Rails's open source projects with best practices and/or code standard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-source

I would like to know some of the great opensource projects in Rails with some best practices and/or code standard including unit testing, so that I can learn some experiences from building apps from those sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Brevidy](https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Brevidy) (very detailed video social network)
2. [Teambox](http://github.com/teambox/teambox) (project management software). I think Teambox is pretty big to mention it;
3. [Redmine](http://github.com/edavis10/redmine) (no comments). Unit testing powered;
4. [Spree](http://github.com/railsdog/spree) (e-commerce). It uses unit testing too.

There is [opensourcerails.com](http://www.opensourcerails.com), but doesn't work right now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't reviewed the projects but this blog article covers just this topic:

http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2010/05/31/five-rails-apps-to-study-and-learn-from.html

Answer (score 0):

redcar looks nice